# Scroll-able area select box as opposed to drop down, Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, select, dropdown

https://www.w3schools.com/html/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_elem_select_size

The select box I see is an area based select box as opposed to a drop down. However, In rails I can only get the drop down based select box. I have tried:

```
<%= f.collection_select :role_cont, Role.where(company: current_user.company), :name, :name, include_blank: true, :multiple => true, class: 'form-control chosen-it', :size => 10 %>
```

The above does not work. Note the :size attribute. From a gem I have:

```
<%= select_tag 'recipients', recipients_options(@chosen_recipient), multiple: true, class: 'form-control chosen-it' %>
```

This does work, it creates an area based select box that I want. How do I set my select boxes to be a scroll able area as opposed to a simple drop down? Also I want to be able to use scroll able select box even when I can only select a singular object

Answer (score 0):

Here why you added ':multiple => true' if you want select only one option,
these option is used when you want to select multiple values from select box.

```
<%= f.collection_select :role_cont, Role.where(company: current_user.company), :name, :name, include_blank: true, :multiple => true, class: 'form-control chosen-it', :size => 10 %>
```

Remove :multiple => true and it work as you want without area based select box

Comment: I tried what you posted, does not work, it is still a dropdown